# Strange behavior with array returned from page.evaluate

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Consider we have this script:

```js
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://google.com', function(status) {

  var ar = page.evaluate(function() {
    // do some magic calculations and return this array:
    return [{ x: 1, y: 10 }, { x: 2, y: 20 }];
  });

  // change the objects inside
  for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        ar[i].y = ar[i].x;
        ar[i].x = 'changed';
    }
  console.log(ar[0].x,ar[0].y);
  console.log(ar[1].x,ar[1].y);

  phantom.exit();
});
```

The result would be:

```
1 10
2 20
```

I solved this with just copying `ar` into new array object:

```js
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://google.com', function(status) {

  var ar = page.evaluate(function() {
    // do some magic calculations and return this array:
    return [{ x: 1, y: 10 }, { x: 2, y: 20 }];
  });

  // shallow copy into new array
  ar = ar.slice(0);
  for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        ar[i].y = ar[i].x;
        ar[i].x = 'changed';
    }
  console.log(ar[0].x,ar[0].y);
  console.log(ar[1].x,ar[1].y);

  phantom.exit();
});
```

The result is:

```
changed 1
changed 2
```

But my question is why this happens?

I'm using phantomjs 1.9.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was raised before in [GitHub issue #10563](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10563). The immutability of returned objects/arrays from page context seems to be [undocumented behavior](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10563#issuecomment-14993450):

> I think this is a "QVariant" behaviour: the returned object is immutable.
>   I don't understand why, and it's not documented explicitly.

The issue contains also some workarounds to convert an immutable object into a normal object like this:

```
result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Before using the result or this:

```
var resultStr = page.evaluate(function() {
    return JSON.stringify(result);
});
var result = JSON.parse(resultStr);
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't find this opened bug on GitHub.